K8s - Does LoadBalancer Service need NodePort?
I was going through this tutorial  and it says that we need to define NodePort when using service type LoadBalancer.
But I've seen implementation of LoadBalancer service types without providing nodePort. How does this work and which is correct?
screenshot:


The service type LoadBalancer is based on the cloud provider. In some cases the load balancer if you don’t specify the nodeport, then the cloud provider will automatically assign the node port.
From kubernetes official document:

You can configure a load balanced Service to omit assigning a node port, provided that the cloud provider implementation supports this. Some cloud providers allow you to specify the loadBalancerIP. In those cases, the load-balancer is created with the user-specified loadBalancerIP. If the loadBalancerIP field is not specified, the load balancer is set up with an ephemeral IP address. If you specify a loadBalancerIP but your cloud provider does not support the feature, the loadbalancerIP field that you set is ignored.

The LoadBalancer Service will contain the same information as a NodePort Service, but adding the Load Balancer’s IP address, which can be located under status.loadblancer.ingress field. However, this IP address will be different from the value assigned to clusterIP and the nodePort will not be relevant to reach the Load Balancer. Client will use the Load Balancer IP address instead and the port to reach the container behind the Service.
So, both the methods are correct and can be used as per your use case. Check this Disabling load balancer NodePort allocation document for more information.
